# How to use aioschedule scheduler without blocking asynctelebot

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, schedule, telebot

Hello everyone I am writing a telegram bot on AsyncTelebot and I ran into such a problem that I can't start the task scheduler without blocking the bot's work. There is the following code snippet:

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule as schedule

...

async def send_price_update_notifications():
    print("Check notifications: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    ...

async def send_notifications():
    await send_price_update_notifications()


async def run_notifications():  
    schedule.every(10).seconds.do(send_notifications)

    while True:
        await schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def start_bot():
    while True:
        await bot.polling(none_stop=True)
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(run_notifications())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(start_bot())

    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())`
```

As a result, the task scheduler is running, and the telegram bot doesn't respond to requests. When the task scheduler is disabled, the bot starts working again. I was dealing with the competitive execution of the code and asyncio, it seems like I'm returning control from each coroutine at the end of execution to the general event loop, but, apparently, I haven't fully figured it out and I don't see some details. Please tell me how to fix it?

[Output img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i77DX.png)

[The bot is not responding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEQkp.png)

I tried to use the event loop explicitly, but nothing has helped so far

Answer (score 0):

Use [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html) instead. Example:

```
import asyncio
from apscheduler.schedulers.asyncio import AsyncIOScheduler
from datetime import datetime
import telebot

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
        self.scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()

    async def scheduled_task(self):
        print("Scheduled task executed.")

    def run_scheduled_tasks(self):
        self.scheduler.add_job(
            self.scheduled_task, 
            "cron", 
            hour=10, minute=30, second=0
        )
        self.scheduler.start()

    async def polling(self):
        task1 = asyncio.create_task(self.bot.infinity_polling())
        self.run_scheduled_tasks()
        await task1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = Bot()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(b.polling())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
        loop.close()
```